# When I do pd.read_csv('FileName.csv', index_col=[0], parse_dates = [0]) it's different from pd.read_csv('FileName.csv'), when I do .dtypes(), why?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, pandas-resample

When I do pd.read_csv('FileName.csv'), I get the time column separate along with the rest of the data as shown:

[image]

When I do pd.read_csv('FileName.csv', , index_col=[0], parse_dates = [0]), knowing time in my data is index 0,I get this:

[image]

I checked the type of each and they are the same, however, when I try to do some analysis it work on one and it doesn't work on the other, like the resample function, it only work with the second dataframe.

Also, I can't use the time column in the second command. I have been looking but maybe am not familiar with key words, I would really appreciate the help! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is related to index. In the first case, there is a separate index column (you can see in it the values 0, 1, ...). In the second case, the index is actually your `Time` column. So as resampling works only when you have a datetime-like index, the second approach works. But you cannot access the values of the index using `Time` column name (use `.index` if you need).

Comment: Thank u! So is there is a way to convert between the two cases? I am trying to resample my data and then use it with FbProphet for forecasting. Prophet only works if time is not indexed. So what I did is I made my time as the index then resampled, then saved the dataframe as a csv file, then read it without the parse to over come this problem. But I feel that this is tedious and maybe there is more direct way

Comment: Yes, after resampling, you can call `reset_index`, and then rename the column from `index` to `Time`.

Comment: Thank u! Appreciate ur help. How can I do resampling while my timestamp data have a timezone GMT-7? I stripped down my time stamp from the time zone, but when the daylight-change happens on March, the resample gives me NaN during this hour change. I got an advice to convert it to UTC

Comment: Actually, I have never faced with this issue, so I have no clue. However, it seems that you can use `.tz_convert("UTC")` method call to convert a datetime column.